# Como chamar a impressora em uma página feita no ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

Gostaria de chamar a impressora mesmo que a página estiver sendo acessada pelo celular.

```
<div class="container droppedHover">

    <div class="row">
        <div class="span6">
            <button class="btn btn-lg btn-block btn-success glyphicon glyphicon-print" type="submit" >  Impressão</button>
            <a href="@Url.Action("Index", "MenuPrincipal")" class="btn btn-lg btn-block btn-warning glyphicon glyphicon-hand-left">
                Retorno
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Faz um bom tempo que está no site, já sabe que se uma resposta respondeu a pergunta oi ideal é aceitá-la. Não digo que sejao caso, pode ser que não te serviu, mas sempre que resolveu o problema poderia aceitar. Que tal fazer uma revisão em todas suas perguntas com respostas sem aceitação para ver quais podem ser aceitas? Não estou dizendo que deva sair aceitando tudo, apenas o que realmente resolveu seu problema.

Answer (score 4):

É só criar um evento para abrir a janela de impressão:

```
<div class="container droppedHover">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="span6">
            <button class="btn btn-lg btn-block btn-success glyphicon glyphicon-print" type="submit" onClick="window.print()">  Impressão</button>
            <a href="@Url.Action("Index", "MenuPrincipal")" class="btn btn-lg btn-block btn-warning glyphicon glyphicon-hand-left">
                Retorno
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/HTML_CSS/CallPrinter.html).

Comment: Eu vou fazer um teste, mais se eu estiver acessando em um celular isso também vai funcionar? agradeço a ajuda

Comment: Não sei dizer, tem uma impressora ligada ao celular? :) Quando a pessoa quer imprimir algo normalmente ela usa o desktop. Celular não é um computador completo. Tem que usar a ferramenta certa para cada coisa.

Comment: como é um sistema que pode ser acessado via celular, então é possível enviar para a impressora, todo celular tem esta opção, vou ter que testar para ver se vai funcionar porque o comando parece ser apenas do windows

Comment: O fato de poder não quer dizer que deva fazer.